# Import mobile specific nativescript plugin in NathaWalker angular-seed-advanced

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin, angular-seed-advanced

I recently started working on Nativescript. I found NathanWalker's angular-seed-advanced quite interesting. I am facing one issue in that. How do I import mobile specific nativescript's plugin in my components as that component is being used for web app too.

If I import directly nativescript plugins in src/client/app/components then Web app will not work as expected. I need to know how to import plugin safely so that both web app and mobile app work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can import mobile specific items in Root module file which is - **[native.module.ts](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/blob/master/nativescript/src/native.module.ts)**.

[Code organization](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced#code-organization-overview) section in the same seed project read me file gives good picture of what file is for what, including the above one.

Hope this helps :)